# AVCaptureConnection videoOrientation AVCaptureConnectionPreviewlayer orientation iOS

Tags: ios, camera, orientation

I am trying to make an app which shows camera preview, and clicks an image when pressed a button.

I wanted to rotate the preview when the device was rotated, so i was using

Till now I was using `previewlayer.orientation = toInterfaceorientation` in the `willAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method. But now when I run my app on iOS6, I get a warning that `setOrientation` method of preview layer is now deprecated.

Also, I think now that that was only to 'view' the preview, the actual orientation of the image won't be changed, it would remain as whatever my video orientation of the 'connection' is!

So, it is suggested to use the `setVideoOrientation` method of the AVCaptureConnection. I am trying to use that but I don't get what to do.. I want to support landscape left and right (and may be portrait modes too later).

So I write in `willAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

```
  `if([connection isVideoOrientationSupported])  
    {  
        if(toInterfaceorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)  
        {  
           [connection setVideoorientation:AVCaptureConnectionVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];  
        }    
if(toInterfaceorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)  
        {  
           [connection setVideoorientation:AVCaptureConnectionVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];  
        }  
    }`
```

But that doesn't really work, it works fine in case of LandscapeRight, but in case of LandscapeLeft it is rotated by 180 degrees.

I have checked that `willAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method is being called, and the statements inside the of blocks are being executed (by setting breakpoints), though the resultant orientations are as if this method was empty!

And I am hoping that this would also change the actual orientation of the image.

Comment: maybe try `setVideoOrientation:` as apposed to `setVideoorientation:` I would be surprised if this is your problem, but hey